# Create a product from code in SFCC

Tags: api, product, commerce-cloud

Is it possible to create a product in code in Commerce Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Out of the box,](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FOCAPI%2Fcurrent%2Fdata%2FDocuments%2FProduct.html) you have a product SKU (which functions as an ID of a product), a manufacturer SKU and a Universal Product Code (UPC). You can also [add your own fields](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/CustomObjects/BusinessObjects.html?cp=0_5_16) to any *business object* (and [retrieve them via API](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FCatalogs%2FCatalogCreationChecklist.html&cp=0_1_7_1), as one way). See [catalog creation checklist](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FCatalogs%2FCatalogCreationChecklist.html&cp=0_1_7_1) for a high-level sequence of steps.

Comment: Hello. I am sorry, I am not getting your answer. Are there any API for the dw.catalog.Product creation? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of APIs. Have a look at the docs: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp

Comment: Please, point me to a specific method which would create a product. Thank you.

Comment: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/data/Resources/Products.html